# How do I log back into a Windows Server 2003 guest OS after Hyper-V integration services installs and breaks my domain logins?

Tags: windows-server-2003, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

After installing Hyper-V integration services, I appear to have a problem with logging in to my Windows Server 2003 virtual machine. Incorrect passwords and logins give the usual error message, but a correct login/password gives me this message:

> Windows cannot connect to the domain, either because the domain
>   controller is down or otherwise unavailable, or because your computer
>   account was not found. Please try again later. If this message
>   continues to appear, contact your system administrator for assistance.

Nothing pleases me more than Microsoft telling me (the ersatz system administrator) to contact my system administrator for help, when I suspect that I'm hooped. The virtual machine has a valid network connection, and has decided to invalidate all my previous logins on this account, so I can't log in and remotely fix anything, and I can't remotely connect to it from outside either. This appears to be a catch 22. Unfortunately I don't know any non-domain local logins for this virtual machine, so I suspect I am basically hooped, or that I need ophcrack.  is there any alternative to `ophcrack`?

Second and related question;  I used Disk2VHD to do the conversion, and I could log in fine several times, until after the Hyper-V integration services were installed, then suddenly this happens and I can't log in now - was there something I did wrong?  I can't get networking working inside the VM BEFORE I install integration services, and at the very moment that integration services is being installed, I'm getting locked out like this. I probably should always know the local login of any machine I'm upgrading so I don't get stuck like this in the future.... great. Now I am reminded again of this.

Comment: also you get a new nic when you install the IC's and if you don't use dhcp you won't be able to connect to the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is right here:

> or because your computer account was not found.

Did you boot the machine that you took the image from? Or did you revert a snapshot of the VM? If so, that's probably what caused this problem.

You will need a local admin account to fix this. Get an ISO with ophcrack or any other rescue CD you want that can crack or change the Windows password. Once you have the password, boot the VM normally and re-join the computer to the domain.

And make sure you have a local password to any computer you P2V in the future!

Comment: This utility worked for me, the first try: http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/